# R chisquare outlier test while loop

Tags: r, while-loop, chi-squared

I am new to R. I want to do a chi-square outlier test, using outliers library on a variable `x$indel` until the returned `p.value is > 0.01` (after removing the outlier from the data).
Here is what I tried:

```
while(chisq.out.test(x$indel)$p.value < 0.01)
{
    # str: string contains the outlier value and some text 
    #   n: extract the outlier value and transform to numeric 
    str <- chisq.out.test(x$indel)$alternative
    print(str)

    n <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(str,
             gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",str))))
    x <- x[x$indel < n,]
    print(nrow(x))
}
```

Below is the x$indel column

```
    c(0.287749287749, 0.324786324786, 0.330484330484, 0.293447293447, 
0.293447293447, 0.31339031339, 0.31339031339, 0.327635327635, 
0.344729344729, 0.327635327635, 0.304843304843, 0.296296296296, 
0.433048433048, 0.700854700855, 0.467236467236, 0.31339031339, 
0.373219373219, 0.293447293447, 0.304843304843, 0.293447293447, 
0.407407407407, 0.301994301994, 0.307692307692, 0.301994301994, 
0.381766381766, 0.307692307692)
```

When I paste this command to the console nothing happens, what's wrong?

Comment: It is hard to help you if you do not supply any data that we can test your code on. Could you please add the output of `dput(head(x$indel, 20))` or similar to the question?

Comment: This seems like a very questionable statistical endeavor.

Comment: I agree with @Roland but since this is SO not CV if you make your example reproducible then I'll give it a shot

Comment: @Backlin I added the complete x$indel

Comment: Can only agree with Roland and Hack-R. @Mariya, it's generally a bad idea to try and remove data until you get significant test results. I assume "indel" means you're working on some genetic data, and if there might be something wrong with your samples (like contamination) you should try to assess that before testing for the outcome you want to study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate some data with "outliers"

```
x = round(rnorm(100, 100, 100), 2)
```

Replaced all `x$indel` with `x`. The problem with using a data.frame is that when you remove values from the column and try to replace the original list, you'll get a complaint about dimension mismatch.

Also improved the regex to handle negative numbers, and improved the subset logic to deal with "highest value" and "lowest value" cases.

```
while(chisq.out.test(x)$p.value < 0.01)
{
  # str: string contains the outlier value and some text 
  #   n: extract the outlier value and transform to numeric 
  str <- chisq.out.test(x)$alternative
  print(str)
  n <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(str,
                                    gregexpr("(?<=value)(.*)(?=is an outlier)", str, perl = T))))
  x <- x[x != n]
  print(length(x))
}
```